# Resume template section modification

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, xetex, alignment

[Link to my tex on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hxncmfxbzjrc)

my current code:

```
% This is a modified ONE COLUMN version of
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (30/4/2014)
% Debarghya Das (http://debarghyadas.com)
% https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX

\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\begin{document}

\namesection{john}{doe}{email | location | website}

\section{Culinary School}
\raggedright

\runsubsection{Extracurriculars}\hfill \location{location | 2019 - 2020}
\begin{tightemize}
    \item tex club
    \item president of gordon ramsay fan club
    \item lorem ipsum
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep
\runsubsection{Athletics}\hfill \location{ }
\begin{tightemize}
    \item Varsity Dodgeball
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\ 
\end{document}
```

converts to this: 
[image: what I don't want]

I want the "location | 2019-2020" to be horizontally aligned with "Culinary School" 
and 
the "Athletics" subsection to horizontally align with "Extracurriculars" 
as illustrated below:

[image: what I want]

How do I do that? I hope this is the right place to ask, I'm still a noob with TeX! 
Again, [here is the link to my code on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hxncmfxbzjrc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here, I answered my own question by using minipages:

```
% This is a modified ONE COLUMN version of
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (30/4/2014)
% Debarghya Das (http://debarghyadas.com)
% https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX

\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

\begin{document}
\namesection{john}{doe}{email | location | website}
\section{Culinary School} \location{location | 2019 - 2020}
\raggedright
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}

\runsubsection{Extracurriculars}\hfill
\begin{tightemize}
    \item tex club
    \item president of gordon ramsay fan club
    \item lorem ipsum
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 
\runsubsection{Athletics}\hfill \location{ }
\begin{tightemize}
    \item Varsity Dodgeball
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep
\end{minipage}

\ 
\end{document}
```

which produces the [desired result](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hxncmfxbzjrc). 
The formatting of the \location element did not allow alignment to the right so I added it below the header.
[image]